# HTML - inserting a margin to body text

Tags: html

I have some text and would like to make it more narrow so it doesn't span right across the screen. I have typed:

```
<body style="margin:20">
<body>
    SQUIRE TRELAWNEY, Dr. Livesey, and the rest of these gentlemen having etc,
<body/>
```

However it doesn't seem to be doing anything to the text. Do I need to close my body style tag? Is margin the correct operator to use? (I am a very beginner, this is literally the first time trying HTML)

Comment: `px` or `%` .......

Comment: use only one `body` tag in your document

Comment: Use only one `<Body>` tag and define margin like `style="margin:20px"` or `margin:20%`

Comment: Not a great idea to add a `margin` on the `body` tag, consider adding a `margin` to a wrapper `div` element

Comment: Yep was missing the px or %. Got rid of the second body tag and it worked fine. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic syntax of an HTML page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration defines this document to be HTML5

The `<html>` element is the root element of an HTML page

The `<head>` element contains meta information about the document

The `<title>` element specifies a title for the document

The `<body>` element contains the visible page content

> There is only one body for HTML.
>   So use `div`, `span`, `p` tags within the body for wrapping your content.

`<body style="margin:20">` is bad code

Try `<body style="margin:20px">` or `<body style="margin:1%">`

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  SQUIRE TRELAWNEY, Dr. Livesey, and the rest of these gentlemen having etc,
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help @user88720

Answer (score 4):

add css on your html,

```
<style>
body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
```

Without css just add style property on your body tag,

```
<body style="margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 100px;margin-right: 150px;margin-left: 80px;">

 SQUIRE TRELAWNEY, Dr. Livesey, and the rest of these gentlemen having etc,

</body>
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do it without CSS? We are not up to CSS just yet

Comment: Thank you. Is that a typical way to use the braces, with an open one, and then the first element indented on the next line like that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove second `<body>` tag
2. Add unit to margin (i.e. px)

   ```
   <body style="margin:20px">
      SQUIRE TRELAWNEY, Dr. Livesey, and the rest of these gentlemen having etc,
   <body/>
   ```

Comment: and use a style tag instead of inline styles